# Read file and create array with first row as header(keys)

Tags: php, arrays, file

I can read the file and put it into an array.

file.txt:

```
 time          value1         value2    

    .00          .0000        21.2310         
 100.92       200.2272         7.7243         
 200.92       222.4021         8.6395
```

My current code:

```
$array = file('file.txt');
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $line) {
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/',';', $line);    
    $line_array = explode("\t", $string);
    $new_array[] = $line_array[0];
}
```

My output:

```
    array
  'time' => 
    array
      0 => string '.00' 
      1 => string '267.1081'  
      2 => string '267.1043'  
  'value1' => 
    array
      0 => string '100.92'  
      1 => string ' 200.2272' 
      2 => string '7.7243'  
  'value2' => 
    array
      0 => string '200.92'  
      1 => string '222.4021'  
      2 => string '8.6395'
```

But the desire I have is:

```
    $my_array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] =>  .00 
            [value1] => .0000 
            [value2] => 21.2310  
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] =>  100.92 
            [value1] => 200.2272  
            [value2] => 7.7243   
        )

     [2] => Array
        (
            [time] =>   200.92 
            [value1] => 222.4021
            [value2] => 8.6395   
        )

)
```

How can I get the first row as keys for the other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first get the file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) where every line is one array element. There I ignore new line characters at the end of each line and skip empty lines.

After this I loop through each line with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and split it with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) by 1 or more spaces. And before I return it I remove empty elements with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Then I get the first innerArray as `$header` with [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

At the end I simply go through all innerArrays again and [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
 the values with the `$header` array.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES |FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $data = array_map(function($v){
        return array_filter(preg_split("/\s+/", $v));
    }, $lines);

    $header = array_shift($data);

    $data = array_map(function($v)use($header){
        return array_combine($header, $v);
    }, $data);

    print_r($data);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => .00
            [value1] => .0000
            [value2] => 21.2310
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 100.92
            [value1] => 200.2272
            [value2] => 7.7243
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [time] => 200.92
            [value1] => 222.4021
            [value2] => 8.6395
        )

)
```