# Convert array from spreadsheet into associative array with header row as keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been having difficulty visualizing how to return a specific array pattern from my extracted array from the spreadsheet table. You may refer to the extracted arrays below.

Here are the extracted arrays from my spreadsheet table

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Order Number
            [1] => Status
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1111
            [1] => Shipped
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2222
            [1] => For Veri
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3333
            [1] => Delivered
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4444
            [1] => Problematic
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5555
            [1] => Onhold
        )

)
```

I would like for the array to be returned as below:

```
 Array(
      [1111] => Array
         {  
          [Order Number] => 1111
          [Status] => Delivered
          }
       [2222] => Array
         {  
          [Order Number] => 2222
          [Status] => Delivered
          }
     )
```

Would like to confirm if the array_combine function would work on this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This has been resolved thanks to
**Markus AO**. Had to make some tweaks with the provided snippets and was able to get the expected result.

```
 //$retrieveArray = extracted arrays from the spreadsheet table.
        $index = null;
        $keys = array_shift($retrieveArray);

        //to declare new set of array
        $named = [];
        
        // to loop the remaining array 
        foreach($retrieveArray as $ln => $vals) {
            $key = !is_null($index) ? $vals[$index] : $ln;
            $named[$key] = array_combine($keys, $vals);
        }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($named);
echo "</pre>";
```

Updated Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Order Number] => 1111
            [Status] => Shipped
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Order Number] => 2222
            [Status] => For Veri
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Order Number] => 3333
            [Status] => Delivered
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Order Number] => 4444
            [Status] => Problematic
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Order Number] => 5555
            [Status] => Onhold
        )

)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `array_combine` would work _as a part of the solution_. There is no single native function to accomplish this, but fortunately it's a fairly simple operation. See the answer. I took the liberty of editing title to match the exact question / need to make this easier for others with the same issue to find: _"Convert array from spreadsheet into associative array with header row as keys"_.

Comment: Related: [PHP CSV to associative array with top row as keys and columns as value arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51828560/2943403) and [PHP CSV to associative array with top row as keys and following rows as values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70072355/2943403) and [Remap CSV as an array using first row as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60338808/2943403) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924314/read-file-and-create-array-with-first-row-as-headerkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29924314/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with spreadsheets and CSV data imported into arrays: The keys become the first array member. It's easy enough to rebuild into an associative array. All we need is to shift the keys off the first row, and then combine them with all remaining values. As follows:

```
function named_keys(array $array, ?int $index = null): array 
{
    // Shift the keys from the first row: 
    $keys = array_shift($array);

    $named = [];
    // Loop and build remaining rows into a new array:
    
    foreach($array as $ln => $vals) {

        // Using specific index or row numbers?
        $key = !is_null($index) ? $vals[$index] : $ln;

        // Combine keys and values:
        $named[$key] = array_combine($keys, $vals);
    }

    return $named;
}
```

*First argument $array* is the source array itself. *Second argument $index* (optional) is the index (numeric) for the value that should be used as the index of the resulting array. If none, row numbers from source array (starting from 1) are used. Works as follows:

```
$raw = [['a', 'b'], [111,'foo'], [333,'bar'], [555,'nix']];

$named = named_keys($raw, 0);

/* // results in:

array(3) {
    [111] · array(2) {
        ["a"] · int(111)
        ["b"] · string(3) "foo"
    }
    [333] · array(2) {
        ["a"] · int(333)
        ["b"] · string(3) "bar"
    }
    [555] · array(2) {
        ["a"] · int(555)
        ["b"] · string(3) "nix"
    }
} */
```

- [Source](https://bitbucket.org/cmswares/stack_overflow/src/master/functions/func.csv_named_keys.php) at BitBucket

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this, was able to get the expected array result from the spreadsheet. Had to make some tweaks to it (Updated snippets provided on the main thread).

Comment: Glad it worked. Looking at what you updated into your post, you've basically just stripped the function off. `$newArray = named_keys($retrieveArray, null)` would work just the same? N.B. Your sample output used the value in `[0]` (e.g. 1111) as the index, which is the only reason the `$index` variable is there to begin with. If you only need the row numbers and the `Order Number` is not significant, you could just do away with the `$index` altogether, and just use `$named[$ln]` or even `$named[]`.

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely use this for future reference. Have a great day!